# Authenticated user doesn't get updated in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, angularfire, angular-promise

I'm using the AngularFire example for ui-router.

```
// for ui-router
app.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
  if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
    $state.go("home");
  }
});
}]);

app.config(["$stateProvider", function ($stateProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state("home", {
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    templateUrl: "views/home.html",
    resolve: {
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$waitForAuth();
      }]
    }
  })
  .state("account", {
    controller: "AccountCtrl",
    templateUrl: "views/account.html",
    resolve: {
      "currentAuth": ["Auth", function(Auth) {
        return Auth.$requireAuth();
      }]
    }
  });
}]);

app.controller("HomeCtrl", ["currentAuth", function(currentAuth) {
}]);

app.controller("AccountCtrl", ["currentAuth", function(currentAuth) {
}]);
```

Everything works for the first user. The problem is that when the first user logs out and the second one logs in, the "currentAuth" still holds the first user's information. Why doesn't it get updated with the new login?

It actually gets updated if I refresh the page, but how can I load the new data without refreshing?

Comment: You'll need to recreate `Auth` to get an updated promise. The simplest answer here is to refresh. Is that really so terrible? You're going to find state all over your app that's invalid after switching users.

Comment: @Kato, thanks, but I'm making a ionic application. I simplified the example. I don't know if "refreshing a page" applies to an app.